# Is it safe for Harry to become an Auror?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry plans to die a natural death thereby breaking the power of Elder wand,

> “I’m putting the Elder Wand,” he told Dumbledore, who was watching him with enormous affection and admiration, “back where it came from. It can stay there. If I die a natural death like Ignotus, its power will be broken, won’t it? The previous master will never have been defeated. That’ll be the end of it.
>
> Dumbledore nodded. They smiled at each other.
>
> <sup>*-Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 36: "The Flaw in the Plan"</sup>

But Auror job includes many incidents during which he need to fight duels or just have to fight to protect himself, during which any enemy can cast expelliarmus and can become the owner of Elder wand thereby continuing the chain,

So is Harry safe to do an Auror job?